# Cannot install package or update on Ubuntu getting dependency error

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am getting error when trying to `sudo apt-get install package_name` on my **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64)** the error Says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg8 (= 8d-1+deb7u1) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It says me to run `apt-get -f install` but when I run it throws me with this error

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjpeg-turbo8 linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjpeg8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjpeg8
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/138 kB of archives.
After this operation, 267 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libjpeg8
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
(Reading database ... 131020 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg8:amd64 (8d-1+deb7u1) over (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.4.2-0ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am unable to install any packages due to this error.
 I tried removing **libjpeg8-dev** by `sudo apt-get remove libjpeg8-dev` and `sudo apt-get purge libjpeg8-dev`
ended up getting errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
 libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg8 (= 8d-1+deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libtiff5 : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-8-jre-headless : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-9-jre-headless : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

tried `sudo apt autoremove`got another error

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg8 (= 8d-1+deb7u1) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

how to solve this

I am getting this error after I tried to install **libjpeg8**

the output of my `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libjpeg8-dev:amd64:
 libjpeg8-dev:amd64 depends on libjpeg8 (= 8d-1+deb7u1); however:
  Version of libjpeg8:amd64 on system is 8c-2ubuntu8.

dpkg: error processing package libjpeg8-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libjpeg-dev:amd64:
 libjpeg-dev:amd64 depends on libjpeg8-dev; however:
  Package libjpeg8-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libjpeg-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libjpeg8-dev:amd64
 libjpeg-dev:amd64
```

my source.list is

```
ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

Comment: run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: can you post the output of `cat etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I have updated my question with what you have asked could you please check again. @George

Comment: I have updated my question with what you have asked could you please check again. @Olimjon

Comment: Comment the last two lines of `sources.list` with `##` and run `sudo apt update` on terminal. Then try `apt -f install`

Comment: To do this you can use `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I worked thank you. Could you please tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: The two last repo in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` are for an earlier version of Ubuntu, you must have added it.